# What is the idiom for "enjoy it!" in Russian?

Tags: idioms

What is the idiom for "enjoy it!" in Russian?

Contexts for example:

> - "I'm going to travel with my friends."
> - "I'm traveling with my friends."
> - "We are in the camp now."
> - "We are walking in the city center now."

I've tried dictionaries and googling but it's not clear.

Comment: _Наслаждайтесь!_ is the closest equivalent.

Comment: *Наслаждайтесь!* is usually malevolent or sarcastic.

Comment: Depends on context. 'Here's your lobster. Enjoy it!' The proper Russian version here would be: "... _приятного аппетита!_". Situations suitable for the Russian imperative "наслаждайтесь!" are **super rare**, despite you can _often_ find that word in poor translations from English.

Comment: Context is definitely needed.

Answer (score 8):

Take the action they are about to enjoy and add "отли́чного/прия́тного":

- "I'm going to travel with my friends." - Enjoy! =
  Я собира́юсь в путеше́ствие с друзья́ми - Отли́чного путеше́ствия!
- "I'm traveling with my friends." - Enjoy! = 
  Я путеше́ствую с друзья́ми - Отли́чного/прия́тного путеше́ствия!
- "We are in camp now." - Enjoy! = 
  Мы в ла́гере. - Прия́тного о́тдыха!
- "We are walking in the city center now." - Enjoy! = 
  Мы гуля́ем по це́нтру го́рода. - Прия́тной прогу́лки!

This will test your ability to take a verb and form a noun. Not always trivial. Or sometimes the action is implied, e.g. what are they doing in the camp? - Having a rest, отдыха́ют.

The way to say "Enjoy your meal" is "Прия́тного аппети́та!". I miss being able to say that because it's not used as frequently in English.

"Have a good time" would be:

- "Отли́чно провести́ вре́мя!" (neutral).
- "Оторви́сь там, оттопы́рься" (slang).

"Наслажда́йся / наслажда́йтесь" is a *calque* of the English "Enjoy!" and definitely **not** the idiomatic way to say it. Although some people do use it, usually in a sarcastic way.

Answer (score 8):

There's no generic way to "enjoy" something in Russian. The construction is action-dependent. Namely: is the enjoyable thing being eaten, smoked, worn, spent (as in time or money), etc? The closest I can give to a recipe is to take the action verb and modify it with some "positive" adverb such as приятно/полезно. Alternatively, you can take the construction suggested above (say, "Отлично провести время!") and indicate where you wish this enjoyment to take place: за едой, на уроках, etc.

Answer (score 8):

**Наслаждайся**, - (literal) the closest generic equivalent.
**Получи удовольствие**, - (literal) not exact equivalent (verbose), but depends on the context
**Удовлетворись**, - (literal)sounds more sarcastic, but, depends on the context.
**Подавись** - (not literal) angry. literally: Сhoke on it!

Comment: Удовлетворись shouldn't be in this list

Comment: Hmm, I wonder, why. I feel, that if it would be me, asking the question, I would want to know all possibilities. Let the questionee decide what variant (s)he needs to use, depending on the context.

Comment: that's not idiomatic and no one speaks that way.

Answer (score 2):

Oh, the problem of enjoyment in a language lacking verbs *to enjoy*, *to like* and *to need*...

The equivalent depends on a context. If you want to be sarcastic, you just say ***Удачи!*** in an appropriate tone.

If you want to wish something pleasant, you just use a structure like 'have a nice / enjoyable + smth!''. In other words, you have to specify what is 'it' you wish an addressee to enjoy. The structure is not so simple to a native English speaker, e. g.:

***Приятных           уроков!***

nice-GEN.PL.MASC. lesson-GEN.PL.MASC.

***Приятной          зарплаты!***

good-GEN.SG.FEM. salary-GEN.SG.MASC.

***Приятного               воскресенья!***

enjoyable-GEN.SG.NEUT.  Sunday-GEN.SG.NEUT.

With words referring to *it* as a time unit or as an event, the adjective ***приятный*** is interchangable with ***счастливый***.

***Счастливого              воскресения!***

enjoyable-GEN.SG.NEUT.   resurrection-GEN.SG.NEUT.