# English "for + verb"? eg 'I need to buy supplies for camping.' There are "for + noun"

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

I could not find a similar question, though I find it hard to search for "for noun stackexchange Russian"...

There are prepositions and/or cases that are used together to say the English equivalent of “for”, but always with a following noun - **“for” + noun** - e.g.

```
I want to walk to the store for bread. 
Я хочу́ идти́ в лавку/магазин за хлебом. ('for' <-> за + instrumental)

I bought the watch as a gift for my sister. 
Я купил часы в подарок для моей сестры. ('for' <-> для + genitive)
```

and others - for example from this website: https://www.alphadictionary.com/rusgrammar/for.html

---

But how to say in Russian the **“for” + verb** construct?

```
I want to buy shoes for running. 

I need to buy supplies for camping.
```

In some sense, in admittedly certain situations, I realize that the verb is unnecessary, e.g.

```
'I want to go to the store for bread.', 
versus, 
'I want to go to the store to buy bread'.
```

Here a noun is used...

```
Па́рень име́ет тала́нт к та́нцам.
The guy has a knack for dancing.
```

Here again a noun is used (I think similar to слушание, чтение, мышленеи, написание, поднятие,...)

```
Учи́тель наказа́л ученика́ за разгово́ры на уро́ке. 
The teacher punished the student for talking during class.
```

I also realize some Russian verbs seemingly (via the dictionary anyway) incorporate the 'dangling preposition' 'for' in the definition, e.g.

```
болеть - to root for
Я болею за TEAM-A. 
I root for TEAM-A.
```

or with the English preposition 'on',

```
наступи́ть - to step on
Он извини́лся, что наступи́л колле́ге на ногу.
He apologized for stepping on his colleague's foot.
```

But I imagine there is a way to deal with the "for + verb" in Russian... or does it just never happen?

PS. Possibly "for + verb" is also bad English.... I never realized how little grammar I knew of English until I started learning Russian.

Comment: There is only one actual question in your question: "But how to say in Russian the “for” + verb construct?" and indeed you give examples like 'for camping', where camping is not exactly a verb. Please consider doing some more research and perhaps edit the question to make it more specific. [Gerund](https://www.quora.com/How-are-verbs-participles-and-gerunds-different)

Comment: yeah, actually I completely forgot about some constructs that answer my question. I will probably close this question so it doesn't pollute the pool.. :)

Comment: I have also crashed into this question once as a student. Actually we are talking about *nominalizations* rather than verbs, i.e. nouns (or adjectives) that are created from verbs. E.g. плавать -> плавание, готовить -> готовка, etc..

Comment: "I will probably close this question"  - it's totally up to you but at least one person upvoted the question, so someone has found it interesting :)

Comment: well i have had questions about participles and gerunds before, as well as nouns like M.P. mentioned (often with suffixes -ка, -ание, -ение,...) but I specifically was looking for a "for + verb" (thinking along the lines of ',чтобы'). Btw, what would you call "camping"? or "glamping"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That’s actually a very good question.

You have two main options: take the verb you are thinking of and turn it into a noun or an adjective:

- о́бувь для та́нцев / танцева́льная о́бувь (shoes for dancing / dancing shoes)
- еда́ для похо́да / похо́дная еда́ (supplies for camping / camping supplies)
- бассе́йн для пла́вания / пла́вательный бассе́йн (pool for swimming / swimming pool)

These options are not entirely equivalent and some may sound better than others in certain situations.

There is also option 1b where the noun gets pluralized: о́бувь для та́нцев VS о́бувь для бе́га  (NOT: для бего́в). «О́бувь для та́нца» (singular) would mean shoes made for a particular kind of dance.

Sometimes it’s not possible to form an adjective so noun is your only option: пры́гать с парашю́том (‘to skydive’) -> снаряже́ние для прыжко́в с парашю́том (‘skydiving gear’).

Neither option is easy because the way nouns and adjectives are formed depends on a particular word:

- бе́гать -> бег, бегово́й
- пла́вать -> пла́вание, пла́вательный (NOT *плав OR *плавовой)
- рабо́тать -> рабо́та, рабо́чий (NOT *работание OR *работательный)
- танцева́ть -> та́нцы, танцева́льный
- ходи́ть в похо́д -> похо́д, похо́дный

(You thought case ending were the hardest thing to learn, eh?)

Sometimes there are multiple adjectives to go with different words:

- игра́ть -> игра́, игрово́й (стол), игра́льный (ко́сти), игри́вый, игри́стый...

Sometimes there is no adjective at all for no apparent reason:

- отдыха́ть -> о́тдых, ??
- пры́гать -> прыжки́, ?? (occasionally, *пры́гательный is possible but it's not a real word)

So you’re stuck with the noun option again:

- ко́мната (для) о́тдыха (a room for rest / NOT a restroom!)

Comment: See also this answer for more examples of nominalization: https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/14369/2104

Comment: Thanks (and @M.P.) for info about: nominalization. and the link and plenty of examples.

Answer (score 4):

Russian language does not have a [Gerund](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund). "For + [verb]-ing" construction does depend on a gerund. To express similar meaning, Russian either use "for + [noun]" or "for the purpose of [verb]" or "for doing + [noun]"

- buy shoes for running - "купить обувь для бегания" - WRONG
- for + [noun]: "купить обувь для бега" - BETTER
- for the purpose of [verb]: "купить обувь для того, чтобы бегать" - OK
- for doing + [noun]: "купить обувь для занятий бегом" - PROBABLY THE BEST (in this particular case)

Note that this issue here exist only for as long as there is no Russian word corresponding to a gerund, like "running" - "бегание" (understandable, but wrong). If such a word exist, translation is straightforward, for example:

- to buy a cap for swimming - "купить шапочку для плавания"

Comment: In some (marginal) constructs the Russian infinitive does fill nominal valencies, thus resembling a gerund: "как насчет выпить?", "перерыв на покурить", etc. So theoretically one could say "обувь на побегать" :) http://www.rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3#241

Comment: @Sergey Slepov - yes, this is another option, but more colloquial one.